# How to convert List<Dapper.SqlMapper.FastExpando> to runtime type (List<IDictionary<string,object>>)

Tags: c#, linq, casting, dapper, dynamic-language-runtime

I'm using a method that has a return signatur of `IEnumerable<dynamic>`. At runtime for a particular call it is returning `List<Dapper.SqlMapper.FastExpando>`.

```
var x0 = repo.Find(proc, param); 
//x0 runtime type is {List<Dapper.SqlMapper.FastExpando>}
```

`LINQPad.Extensions.Dump` indicates the runtime type of `x0` is: `List<IDictionary<String, Object>>` but I can't seem to cast/convert to `List<IDictionary<String, Object>>`. 
Here is a screenshot of the Linqpad Dump:
[image]

Ultimately I need to join all the Values from each Dictionary to a single `IEnumerable<DateTime>`.

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDates(int productId) 
{
    const string proc = "[dbo].[myproc]";
    dynamic param = new { Id = "asdf" };
    var x0 = repo.Find(proc, param); 
    //...
    //linq conversion from x0 to IEnumerable<DateTime> here.
}
```

**Error I'm getting**

```
List<IDictionary<String, Object>> x5 = repo.Find(proc, param);
```

results in:

```
RuntimeBinderException: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to
 'System.Collections.Generic
     .List<System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,object>>'.
An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

**BACKGROUND:**
I am using a `Dapper` wrapper and can't change the database table/stored procedure which returns denormalized results. Instead of 100 rows of 1 data element, the sproc returns 1 row of 100 columns. I wanted to avoid creating a class to represent the 100 columns and want to take advantage of `Dapper`'s automagical ability to transpose the column data to rows via an IDictionary of columnName, columnValue.

**UPDATE**
This appears to be an issue with the dynamic param. When specified inline, it works. If specified locally and then passes as a parameter, it fails.

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDates(int productId) 
{
    const string proc = "[dbo].[myproc]";
    dynamic param = new { Id = "asdf" };

    //next line throws RuntimeBinderException: 'object' does not 
    //contain a definition for 'First'.
    //IDictionary<String, object> x0 = repo.Find(proc, param).First();

    //this succeeds:
    IDictionary<String, object> x0 = repo.Find(proc, new { Id = "asdf" }).First();

    IEnumerable<DateTime> qry2
       = x0.Values.AsQueryable()
           .Where(x => x != null)
           .Select(x => (DateTime) x);
    return qry2;
}
```

Here are the signatures for `Find` and `Query`:

```
//Repository::Find
public IEnumerable<dynamic> Find(string procName, object param = null)

//Dapper SqlMapper::Query
public static IEnumerable<dynamic> Query(this IDbConnection cnn, string sql, dynamic param = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null, bool buffered = true, int? commandTimeout = null, CommandType? commandType = null)
```

Comment: When I look at the answers and you comments I think that `repo.Find` returns an object, but it could (and should) be changed into returning an `IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>>`, which is the return type of Dapper's `Query` method. `FastExpando` (in the current source changed to `DapperRow`) implements `IDictionary<string, object>`.

Comment: @GertArnold, @ofstream - it appears to be a subtle issue with the `Dapper` wrapper. It's signature is `public IEnumerable<dynamic> Find(string procName, object param = null)` while the Dapper signature is `public static IEnumerable<dynamic> Query(this IDbConnection cnn, string sql, dynamic param = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null, bool buffered = true, int? commandTimeout = null, CommandType? commandType = null)` so it looks like there is a type conversion going on from `object` to `dynamic` for the param argument. I think changing the wrapper signature to `dynamic param` should fix it.

Comment: It is the return parameter that matters. `.Cast<IDictionary<String, Object>>()` should work (Servy's answer).

Comment: Please see update to my Question. It is an issue with the `dynamic param`

Comment: When an input parameter changes the output there must be an overload of `Find`.

Comment: Not sure if this'll work, but try modifying the signature to Find<T> (string procName, T param = null);

Answer (score 2):

You can use the LINQ `Cast` method to cast each item in the sequence.

```
List<IDictionary<String, Object>> data = repo.Find(proc, param)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Cast<IDictionary<String, Object>>()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I get a RuntimeBinderException on that line: `'object' does not contain a definition for 'Cast'`

Comment: @JayWalker Add in an `AsEnumerable` if it's actually an `IQueryable` and not an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: With that change I get: `'object' does not contain a definition for 'AsEnumerable'`. repo.Find returns an IEnumerable<dynamic>. I also changed to `var data` and got same Exception.

Comment: @Servy That method returns object.

Answer (score 1):

`Repo.Find` does not return an `IEnumerable<dynamic>`. It returns `object`. If you are sure it will always return a `List<IDictionary<String, Object>>` just do this:

```
List<IDictionary<String, Object>> x5 = (List<IDictionary<String, Object>>)repo.Find(proc, param);
```

Comment: I get a RuntimeBinderException of 'object' does not contain a definition for 'AsEnumerable'. Looks like the runtime type is:  `System.Collections.Generic.List<Dapper.SqlMapper.FastExpando>` when I use `var x5 = repo.Find()`

Comment: Please see update to my Question. It is an issue with the `dynamic param`

Comment: That is REALLY odd. I'll see if I can find out why.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is that by specifying param as `dynamic` causes the method to be dynamically invoked and extension methods can no longer be chained.

So you could just use `var` instead of `dynamic`:

```
 var param = new { Id = "asdf" };
 var data = repo.Find(proc, param)
.Cast<IDictionary<String, Object>>()
.ToList();
```

Or just cast the `dynamic` param to `object` before invoking:

```
 var data = repo.Find(proc, (object)param)
.Cast<IDictionary<String, Object>>()
.ToList();
```

Or if `Find` really is returning a runtime type of `System.Collections.Generic.List<Dapper.SqlMapper.FastExpando>` just cast the result to `dynamic` to make sure that it uses it's runtime type before assigning it, and it is important to assign  to `IEnumerable<>` specifically because it is a co-variant type (`IList<>` or `List<>` will fail).

```
IEnumerable<IDictionary<String, Object>> data = (dynamic) repo.Find(proc, param);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Don't pass back dynamic from your method.    Dapper has a ToList< T > extension method, so you can cast to any supported type.  In this case if you really need the low level associative array, pass back List< Dictionary < string, object > >.

It's also worth noting C# dynamic does not marshal across assembly boundaries, so that may have potentially been an issue you encountered.  If you're marshaling across assemblies, you'd want to use Expando, List< Dictionary < string, object > >, or some other type that is referenced by both assemblies.

### Explanation

Here's an older version of the [Dapper SQLMapper source](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/source/browse/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs?r=c9160c13fb45eb512f66524825612397aa3728ba) that includes FastExpando (line 941).
Notice the class definition for FastExpando.

private class FastExpando : System.Dynamic.DynamicObject, IDictionary< string, object >

Comment: Not sure why DapperDev team made FastExpando private.  There are use cases for flowing data from a relational DB, applying some light data massaging, and then sending on to a NO-SQL store.  Making FastExpando a first-class citizen would make these sorts of scenarios a little less opaque to deal with.